# Removing space from a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I have written the following Html/css. I can't find a way to remove the white space around the "hello". I would also love to center them both in screen (while leaving 'hello' & 'World' - left aligned) - However the white spacing around the hello is what's making my head in.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="row" style="border:solid 1px green;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 gauche" style="text-align:left;border:solid 1px red;width:120px;">
    <span style="font-size:14px;height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;">hello</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-5" style="vertical-align:middle;">
    <span style="font-size:14px;height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;">World</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a [mcve] as with the info provided there should be nothing causing that space.  What framework are you using?

Comment: Unable to reproduce - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jywNZy

Comment: why you specify height twice: 20px, and 100px `height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;` for both hello span and world span? Also, when i run your code snippet, there is no white space around Hello! whats your browser?

Comment: And another tip: whats that `gauche` class you applied to the Hello parent div? may be it has some padding/margin?

Comment: maybe a french version of bootstrap?

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
            
body * {
    text-align: left;
}
            
.row {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div class="row" style="border:solid 1px green;display: inline-block;">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 gauche" style="text-align:left;border:solid 1px red;display:inline-block;">
            <span style="font-size:14px;height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;">hello</span>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-lg-5" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <span style="font-size:14px;height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;">World</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how does this remove the white space around the hello?

Comment: The white space you refer to in the code I provided is actually an empty space. It can be semantically removed by commenting it out, but you cannot make two words of different size allign to both sides nor make the div border that goes around it to adapt shape other than a rectangular shape..

Comment: P.S. did you even try the whole code I gave you or did you just copy the HTML with the inline part?

Comment: The white space the OP talks about, they haven't provided the code to reproduce it, so how you think you can solve it without the cause is interesting

Comment: Regardless of the answer being marked as bad, I guess the problem is as usual that between any tags where there is a whitespace, there has to be an HTML comment to prevent it from happening. Like in this case </span><!-- new lines here --></div><!-- new lines here --><div>... etc. Some people resolve this by adding -4px margin to following elements, which in this case would be a second span. If this is the case, the question could have been better explained..

Comment: you need to understand html and css a little better, white space will only occur between inline / inline-block elements.  They will not occur between the end of a span and the end of a div

Comment: Example 1:
<span style="font-size:14px;height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;">hello</span>
NEWLINE
<span style="font-size:14px;height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;">World</span>

Example 2:
<span style="font-size:14px;height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;">hello</span><!-- NEWLINE

--><span style="font-size:14px;height:20px;border:solid 1px red;height:100px;">World</span>

First one will compile a whitespace in the browser even if there is none added. The second one won't.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was referring to the code that was in the question. There are multiple new lines between divs. You're right about the span-div part.